# Showing HTTP response in Rails - undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, ruby-on-rails-5, httparty

I'm using the HTTParty gem, Rails 5, and the "httplog" gem.

I traced my HTTP request using the "httplog" gem and I received the correct JSON response. Due to this, I believe that my issue is occurring in my view. I am accessing the API properly from the model. I am utilizing it correctly in the controller as per the HTTP log. I'm just flubbing up somewhere between my view and controller.

I'm getting an **"undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass"** error when accessing the API.

Here is an example response from the API:

```
{
    "result_count": 8132,
    "page_size": 250,
    "current_page": 1,
    "total_pages": 33,
    "api_call_credits": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "ticker": "A",
            "name": "Agilent Technologies Inc",
            "lei": "QUIX8Y7A2WP0XRMW7G29",
            "cik": "0001090872",
            "latest_filing_date": "2017-02-06"
        }
```

Here is my model:

```
class Finance < ApplicationRecord
  include HTTParty

  def self.response
    auth = {
    username: "username",
    password: "password"
    }
    options = { basic_auth: auth }
    data_url = "https://api.intrinio.com/companies?ticker=AAPL"
    HTTParty.get(data_url, options)
    end
end
```

My controller:

```
class FinancesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @response = Finance.response
  end
end
```

My View:

```html
<% @response["data"].each do |data| %>
    <p><%= data["name"]%></p>
    <p><%= data["ticker"]%></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I never used HTTP Party but I don't see anywhere where you're "returning" the body of the response, usually you need to something like

```
response = HTTParty.get(data_url, options)
response.body # being this the actual json response
```

IF that works you could do directly this

```
HTTParty.get(data_url, options).body
```

Comment: I could try that. I&#39;m using this gem as above when accessing a number of other APIs and it usually works well. I believe that HTTParty has its own method of parsing JSON automatically.

Comment: You can always print @result to see what's up?

Comment: Could you show an example of how to properly use "@result" to find the error?

Comment: @T.Cole properly I'm not sure, I would perhaps, `response = HTTParty.get(data_url, options)` then `puts response` ? Then see if I need to inspect, iterate wtv. Btw, have you tried with `@response[:data]` ? It seems that in Rails 5 it defaults to symbolizing the keys

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **`parsed_response`** method of `HTTParty::Response` (this is response of your request).
`HTTParty.get(url, data).parsed_response`